# sql select statement over adb

Tags: sqlite, batch-file, adb

I would like to have a batch file that runs a select statement over adb and returns the found rows.
This is the command that I use in my batch file:

```
adb shell "su -c sqlite3 /data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db 'select * from sms;'"
```

The problem I have is, that my command produces an error:

`Error: incomplete input`

What I don’t understand is that the fallowing command works just fine:

```
adb shell "su -c sqlite3 /data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db '.tables'"
```

This returns the tables from the database, as expected.

My guess is, that I need to escape some characters, the “;” maybe, but escaping it with \ or with ^ both did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the semicolon implies there is further input. What does removing it do?

Comment: @Magoo no this does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer would be to use `` `"`" `` to encode `"`.

```
adb shell "su -c 'sqlite3 /data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db `"`"SELECT * FROM sms;`"`"'"
```

I only found out about this thanks to chatGPT.

An alternative would be to use `` `\`" ``. this makes a lot more sense. you escape the `"` with the `\` on the adb side, and then you escape both of these characters with a backtick on the powershell side.

```
adb shell "su -c 'sqlite3 /data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db `\`"SELECT * FROM sms;`\`"'"
```

If someone want’s to loose all sanity one could also add a where clause to the select statement:

```
adb shell "su -c 'sqlite3 /data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db `\`"SELECT body FROM sms WHERE address=`\`\`\`"+41798072042`\`\`\`";`\`"'"
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using powershell, then escape the `;`:

```
adb shell "su -c sqlite3 /data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db 'select * from sms`;'"
```

Comment: sadly escaping it with ` also did not work